query_export_to_s3 split csv in multiple files
I am currently running the following query in AWS RDS Postgres to export data into an s3 bucket. The query works, but I was wondering if there is a way to export and split the csv file into multiple files?
SELECT * FROM aws_s3.query_export_to_s3(
    'select * from products;',
    '(products-dev/products.csv,us-west-2)',
    options := 'format csv, delimiter '','', HEADER true, PROGRAM split' // PROGRAM is not recognized, was hoping to use split library to split the file
);

Any ideas on how to do this would be great! Thank you!

The aws_s3.query_export_to_s3() is using the PostgreSQL COPY command. Thus, the options are actually COPY options.
I cannot see any parameters that can forcibly split the output.
However, I have experienced the situation where it was saved as multiple files after reaching 6GB. That appears to be the size limit for a single file.
